# Using \put command relative to page size

Tags: beamer, diagrams, pdfpages, picture-mode

I want to include a logo in the pdf pages included in [Beamer](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/).

I tried writing macro and progressed so far.

```
\documentclass[fleqn,xcolor=dvipsnames]{beamer}

\newlength{\logosize}
\setlength{\logosize}{7.50mm}

\newlength{\logoXinpdf}
\newlength{\logoYinpdf}
\setlength{\logoXinpdf}{0.9\textwidth}
\setlength{\logoYinpdf}{0.8\textheight}


\usepackage{pdfpages}

\def\getpdfpages#1#2{\begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
  \includepdf[pages={#1},picturecommand={\put(\logoXinpdf,\logoYinpdf){\pgfimage[width=\logosize]{mylogo}}}]{#2}
  \endgroup}


\begin{document}


\getpdfpages{{9,12}}{mypdf.pdf}


\end{document}
```

However, when I run pdfLaTeX, I get an error in the line of,

```
! A <box> was supposed to be here.
<to be read again> 
                   \unitlength 
l.23 \getpdfpages{{9,12}}{mypdf.pdf}
```

I understand that the problem is with the `\put` command. If I replace the `\logoXinpdf,\logoYinpdf` lengths with absolute numbers, everything works fine.

Is there a way I can use these defined lengths with the `\put` command?

Comment: Your mistake here is that arguments of `\put` are in `\unitlength` units, not an usual length. Try to include `fp` package and compute coordinates by dividing your lengths by value of `\unitlength`.

Comment: Thanks, @Eddy_Em. 
Modifying the code in the following manner solved my problem,
   \makeatletter
   \FPdiv{\logoX}{\strip@pt\logoXinpdf}{\strip@pt\unitlength}
   \FPdiv{\logoY}{\strip@pt\logoYinpdf}{\strip@pt   \unitlength}
   \makeatother

    \def\getpdfpages#1#2{\begingroup
    \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
    \includepdf[pages={#1},picturecommand={\put(\logoX,\logoY){\pgfimage[width=\logosize]{buetlogo}}}]{#2}
  \endgroup}

Comment: @MMA: If this solved your problem please post it as an self-answer (after the waiting period) and accept it in order to conclude the question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually sufficient just to locally disable `\unitlength`  (assuming this is a picture mode command internally.

```
\def\getpdfpages#1#2{\begingroup
  \setbeamercolor{background canvas}{bg=}
  \includepdf[pages={#1},picturecommand={{\def\unitlength{}\put(\logoXinpdf,\logoYinpdf){\pgfimage[width=\logosize]{mylogo}}}}]{#2}
  \endgroup}
```

`\put` expects a multiplier and does essentially

```
\setlength\something{#1\unitlength}
\setlength\somethingelse{#2\unitlength}
```

So if `\unitlength` is empty it is OK to pass lengths to put. Heiko's `picture` package takes this a bit further and adds some conditional logic so that you can use either a length or a multiplier, so that `\unitlength` becomes essentially a default unit. So it is probably enough just to load `picture` and make no change to your code.

Comment: Any chance LaTeX will be upgraded to have this as a setting or an option on `{picture}`?

Comment: @DonaldArseneau not impossible, Heiko's package does something along these lines as I noted above.  You could open a feature request at https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/issues so we don't forget until this post next pops up in another 7 years:-)